# C++17 zip iterator compatible with std::sort

Tags: c++, iterator, c++17

Here are ~100 lines of code implementing three classes (`ZipRef`, `ZipIter`, `Zip`) which should satisfy the zip iterator pattern in a STL-compatible way. This means that, unlike `boost::zip_iterator`, `ZipIter` can be safely (I hope!) used in various algorithms like `std::rotate` and `std::sort`. I tried to embrace the power of C++17, aiming at writing much more readable (variadic) template code compared to what allowed by C++11.

Note: maintained on [GitHub](https://github.com/dpellegr/ZipIterator) (includes a usage example and some extra notes), the code in this post is not going to be edited.

```
//
// C++17 implementation of ZipIterator by Dario Pellegrini <pellegrini.dario@gmail.com>
// Still unsure about the licence, but something in the line of just providing attribution
// October 2019
//

#include <tuple>

template <typename ...T>
class ZipRef {
  std::tuple<T*...> ptr;
public:
  ZipRef() = delete;
  ZipRef(const ZipRef& z) = default;
  ZipRef(ZipRef&& z) = default;
  ZipRef(T* const... p): ptr(p...) {}

  ZipRef& operator=(const ZipRef& z)             { return copy_assign( z); }
  ZipRef& operator=(const std::tuple<T...>& val) { return val_assign(val); }

  template <size_t I = 0>
  ZipRef& copy_assign(const ZipRef& z) {
    *(std::get<I>(ptr)) = *(std::get<I>(z.ptr));
    if constexpr( I+1 < sizeof...(T) ) return copy_assign<I+1>(z);
    return *this;
  }
  template <size_t I = 0>
  ZipRef& val_assign(const std::tuple<T...>& t) {
    *(std::get<I>(ptr)) = std::get<I>(t);
    if constexpr( I+1 < sizeof...(T) ) return val_assign<I+1>(t);
    return *this;
  }

  std::tuple<T...> val() const {return std::apply([](auto&&...args){ return std::tuple((*args)...); }, ptr);}
  operator std::tuple<T...>() const { return val(); }

  template <size_t I = 0>
  void swap(const ZipRef& o) const {
    std::swap(*(std::get<I>(ptr)), *(std::get<I>(o.ptr)));
    if constexpr( I+1 < sizeof...(T) ) swap<I+1>(o);
  }

  #define OPERATOR(OP) \
    bool operator OP(const ZipRef & o) const { return val() OP o.val(); } \
    inline friend bool operator OP(const ZipRef& r, const std::tuple<T...>& t) { return r.val() OP t; } \
    inline friend bool operator OP(const std::tuple<T...>& t, const ZipRef& r) { return t OP r.val(); }

    OPERATOR(==) OPERATOR(<=) OPERATOR(>=)
    OPERATOR(!=) OPERATOR(<)  OPERATOR(>)
  #undef OPERATOR

};

template<typename ...IT>
class ZipIter {
  std::tuple<IT...> it;

  template<int N, typename... T> using NthTypeOf =
    typename std::tuple_element<N, std::tuple<T...>>::type;
  template<typename... T> using FirstTypeOf = NthTypeOf<0, T...>;

public:
  using iterator_category = typename std::iterator_traits<FirstTypeOf<IT...>>::iterator_category;
  using difference_type   = typename std::iterator_traits<FirstTypeOf<IT...>>::difference_type;
  using value_type        = std::tuple<typename std::iterator_traits<IT>::value_type ...>;
  using pointer           = std::tuple<typename std::iterator_traits<IT>::pointer ...>;
  using reference         = ZipRef<typename std::iterator_traits<IT>::value_type ...>;

  ZipIter() = default;
  ZipIter(const ZipIter &rhs) = default;
  ZipIter(ZipIter&& rhs) = default;
  ZipIter(const IT&... rhs): it(rhs...) {}

  ZipIter& operator=(const ZipIter& rhs) = default;
  ZipIter& operator=(ZipIter&& rhs) = default;

  ZipIter& operator+=(const difference_type d) { 
    std::apply([&d](auto&&...args){((std::advance(args,d)),...);}, it); return *this;
  }
  ZipIter& operator-=(const difference_type d) { return operator+=(-d); }

  reference operator* () const {return std::apply([](auto&&...args){return reference(&(*(args))...);}, it);}
  pointer   operator->() const {return std::apply([](auto&&...args){return pointer  (&(*(args))...);}, it);}
  reference operator[](difference_type rhs) const {return *(operator+(rhs));}

  ZipIter& operator++() { return operator+=( 1); }
  ZipIter& operator--() { return operator+=(-1); }
  ZipIter operator++(int) {ZipIter tmp(*this); operator++(); return tmp;}
  ZipIter operator--(int) {ZipIter tmp(*this); operator--(); return tmp;}

  difference_type operator-(const ZipIter& rhs) const {return std::get<0>(it)-std::get<0>(rhs.it);}
  ZipIter operator+(const difference_type d) const {ZipIter tmp(*this); tmp += d; return tmp;}
  ZipIter operator-(const difference_type d) const {ZipIter tmp(*this); tmp -= d; return tmp;}
  inline friend ZipIter operator+(const difference_type d, const ZipIter& z) {return z+d;}
  inline friend ZipIter operator-(const difference_type d, const ZipIter& z) {return z-d;}

  #define OPERATOR(OP) \
    bool operator OP(const ZipIter& rhs) const {return it OP rhs.it;}
    OPERATOR(==) OPERATOR(<=) OPERATOR(>=)
    OPERATOR(!=) OPERATOR(<)  OPERATOR(>)
  #undef OPERATOR
};

template<typename ...Container>
class Zip {
  std::tuple<Container&...> zip;

public:
  Zip() = delete;
  Zip(const Zip& z) = default;
  Zip(Zip&& z) = default;
  Zip(Container&... z): zip(z...) {}

  #define HELPER(OP) \
    auto OP(){return std::apply([](auto&&... args){ return ZipIter((args.OP())...);}, zip);}
    HELPER( begin) HELPER( end)
    HELPER(rbegin) HELPER(rend)
  #undef HELPER
};

#include <utility>
using std::swap;
template<typename ...T> void swap(const ZipRef<T...>& a, const ZipRef<T...>& b) { a.swap(b); }

#include <sstream>
template< class Ch, class Tr, class...IT, typename std::enable_if<(sizeof...(IT)>0), int>::type = 0>
auto& operator<<(std::basic_ostream<Ch, Tr>& os, const ZipRef<IT...>& t) {
  std::basic_stringstream<Ch, Tr> ss;
  ss << "[ ";
  std::apply([&ss](auto&&... args) {((ss << args << ", "), ...);}, t.val());
  ss.seekp(-2, ss.cur);
  ss << " ]";
  return os << ss.str();
}
```

Usage example from the [README](https://github.com/dpellegr/ZipIterator#example):

> Consider this minimal example:
>
> ```
> #include <vector>
> #include <string>
> #include <algorithm>
> #include <iostream>
> #include "ZipIterator.hpp" //Header only ;)
>
> int main() {
>   std::vector<int> a{3,1,4,2};
>   std::vector<std::string> b{"Alice","Bob","Charles","David"};
>
>   auto zip = Zip(a,b);
>
>   for (const auto & z: zip) std::cout << z << std::endl;
>   std::cout << std::endl;
>
>   std::sort(zip.begin(), zip.end());
>
>   for (const auto & z: zip) std::cout << z << std::endl;
>   return 0;
> }
> ```
>
> It can be compiled by simply enabling the c++17 (or more recent)
>   standard and the produced output is:
>
> ```
> $ g++ -std=c++17 main.cpp -o main.out && ./main.out
> [ 3, Alice ]
> [ 1, Bob ]
> [ 4, Charles ]
> [ 2, David ]
>
> [ 1, Bob ]
> [ 2, David ]
> [ 3, Alice ]
> [ 4, Charles ]
> ```
>
> Behind the curtain the permutations (either by swapping or copying)
>   applied by `std::sort` to the elements of vector `a` have been
>   simultaneously applied to vector `b` as well.
>
> Note that it would have been possible to zip a third (and more) vector
>   as well, as the implementation leverages on variadic templates.

The reason for `ZipRef` over `std::tuple` is that one needs special constructor, assignment and comparison operators to be able to handle the tuple of pointers with a value-like semantics. One also needs a tuple of pointers because it allows to manipulate the data even if the tuple is constant, so one can extend the lifetime of non-const lvalues references of ZipRef (as the one returned when dereferencing ZipIter) by binding them to const references, while still being able, later, to modify the data being pointed to. Note that the custom swap, quite unusually, takes const references!

Comment: I have copied the usage example on your README file into the question.  This is probably a good idea because it helps make the question more self-contained.  Feel free to roll back if that's not desired :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Lies, damned lies, ... and `iterator_category`

This line from `ZipIter` is a big lie:

```
    using iterator_category = typename std::iterator_traits<FirstTypeOf<IT...>>::iterator_category;
```

Why? Because it unequivocally expands the capabilities of the first iterator type to all the other ones.

This has some bad consequences: Some operations (e.g. `std::sort`) require at least some specific iterator category to work.

Example:

```
auto a = std::vector<std::string>{ "A", "B", "C", "A" };
auto b = std::forward_list<int>{ 4, 3, 2, 1 };

auto zip = Zip(a, b);
std::sort(zip.begin(), zip.end()); // This cannot succeed
```

In this case, `std::sort` requires random access iterators, which `std::vector` does provide. However, `std::forward_list` doesn't (it only provides forward iterators). But `ZipIter` promises that it is a random access iterator, even though random access operations are not supported on some contained iterators.

Ok, `ZipIter::iterator_category` is a lie, but why is it so damning?

Because `iterator_category` is an easy to use feature check (with strong constraints mandated by the standard). So many algorithm implementations just check for `iterator_category`. If you're lucky, they will still fail at compile time, but in some subtler cases you just silently run into undefined behavior.

How to fix this?

Instead of using the first available `iterator_category`, use the minimal `iterator_category` of all provided iterators:

```
    using iterator_category = std::common_type_t<typename std::iterator_traits<IT>::iterator_category...>;
    // this works since more powerful iterator categories inherit from less powerful ones
    // thus the common ancestor tag is supported by all
```

But wait a moment...

Remember when I said that the standard mandates strong constraints for certain iterator categories?

Well, if an iterator wants to be categorized as forward iterator or above, among [other constraints](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ForwardIterator) the following must be true:

> `reference` must be either `value_type&` or `const value_type&`.

Based on this constraint, the most powerful legal `iterator_category` for this iterator is actually `std::input_iterator_tag`. (Which in turn means that `std::sort` won't work at all, as it requires random access iterators.)

> There are arguments to be made why the standard is overly restrictive with this clause, but as of C++17 these are the given requirements and shall not be violated. This is why `boost::zip_iterator` cannot be used with algorithms like `std::sort`: There is no legally possible way to meet all requirements under all circumstances.
>
> Fun fact: `std::vector<bool>::iterator` has the same issue.

## Constant pain

There are some issues with regard to `const`ness.

```
auto a = std::vector<int>{ 1, 2, 3, 4 };
auto b = std::vector<std::string>{ "A", "B", "C", "D" };
const auto c = b;

auto zip_one = Zip(a, b);
auto zip_two = Zip(a, c);

for(auto&& value : zip_one) std::cout << value << "\n"; // this works
for(auto&& value : zip_two) std::cout << value << "\n"; // this fails to compile
```

What happened? `c` is an exact copy of `b` - the only difference being a small `const`. But the consequences are dire: Compilation failure!

What changed? Since `c` is constant, `c.begin()` and `c.end()` only return `const_iterator`s, since elements within should also not change.

How to fix? The culprit in this case is the definition for `ZipIter::reference`:

```
    using reference         = ZipRef<typename std::iterator_traits<IT>::value_type ...>;
```

Using a different definition that takes into account the actual iterator `reference` fixes this:

```
    using reference         = ZipRef<std::remove_reference_t<typename std::iterator_traits<IT>::reference>...>;
```

But the trouble with `const` doesn't end here: Once any type of the template type parameters of `ZipRef` is `const`, some operations of `ZipRef` won't work anymore: assignment fails (`const` values cannot be reassigned) and `swap` fails (same reason). And there is no easy fix for this!

## To the end of the universe... and beyond!

```
auto a = std::vector<std::string>(10, "A");
auto b = std::vector<std::string>(2, "C");

auto zip = Zip(a, b);
std::distance(zip.begin(), zip.end()); // uh oh
```

How many zipped elements should `zip` contain?

Logically, there should at most be two, as there aren't any values in `b` to continue any further.

Instead, the current implementation gives undefined behavior:

```
auto endReached = std::next(zip.begin(), 2);
assert(endReached != zip.end());
```

`endReached` is the `ZipIter` pointing just at `b.end()`, i.e. where the iteration should stop. But the check against `zip.end()` fails, since not all iterators have yet reached their corresponding end iterator.

And this is where undefined behavior happens: `++endReached` advances a past-the-end-iterator, and after that nothing can be trusted anymore.

How can this be fixed?

The most common approach is to use a sentinel value as end iterator so that any `ZipIter` compares `true` if any (instead of all) of its contained iterators matches the corresponding end iterator.

## Licensed trouble (or freedom?)

```
// Still unsure about the licence, but something in the line of just providing attribution
```

When posting the code on this site, you have already released it under the CC-BY-SA 4.0 license. You can of course release it under another license model (you're free to do so as the license holder).

## Other issues

I won't repeat much of [Toby Speight's answer](/a/231546/75307), but some additional notes:

- `ZipRef::swap` is modelled on `std::iter_swap`, not `std::swap`. Maybe the name should be adjusted to reflect this?
- `ZipIter::difference_type` has the same issue as `ZipIter::reference`: It only uses the `difference_type` of the first iterator. (Usually not much of a deal, since most iterators use `std::ptrdiff_t`. Still, beware of the edge case!)
- `ZipRef`s `operator std::tuple<T...>()` is unlikely to work in generic context as intended (conversions are excluded when matching templated arguments, e.g. `std::get<1>(zipRef)` doesn't work). It works in specialized contexts (`void f(std::tuple<std::string, int>); f(zipRef);`, but this might cause unexpected issues.

Comment: Impressive: I found the "const pain" you noted (and forgot to mention it), but couldn't identify a solution.  Thanks for that enlightenment!

Comment: What about `enabling_if` `std::common_type_t<typename std::iterator_traits<IT>::iterator_category...>` is at least `forward_iterator`? It still violates the overly restrictive standard (which one has to take into account when migrating between different implementation of the STL), but otherwise either the idea or the whole standard-conforming ecosystem should be scrapped...

Comment: @DarioP: From what I understand, there are currently some ongoing proposals to amend the c++ standard to allow for these kinds of proxy iterators. (I'm not quite up to date whether it will make C++20, but if it does, just migrate to C++20 and enjoy.) If you are forced to use C++17 though, either accept the `std::input_iterator_tag`, or violate it at your own risk (pretending to be something you are not will very likely lead to UB).

Comment: I think that C++20 will not update the situation. Eric Niebler's range-v3 has been partially adopted, but Zip is one of the few components that were purposely left out. Let's wait for C++23, I guess.

Answer (score 7):

A constant `Zip` can't easily be iterated:

```
  auto const zip = Zip(a,b);

  for (const auto & z: zip) std::cout << z << std::endl;
```

All that's necessary for that to work is to add some `const` operators:

```
  #define HELPER(OP) \
    auto OP() const {return std::apply([](auto&&... args){ return ZipIter((args.OP())...);}, zip);}
    HELPER( begin) HELPER( end)
    HELPER(rbegin) HELPER(rend)
    HELPER( cbegin) HELPER( cend)
    HELPER(crbegin) HELPER(crend)
  #undef HELPER
```

There's still more to do here, as it's surprising that a `const Zip` returns mutable iterators.  Unfortunately, I haven't yet come up with a solution to that problem.  The nearest I got was to separate out the const `(r){begin,end}` like this:

```
#define HELPER(OP)                                                      \
    auto OP() const {return std::apply([](auto&&... args) { return ZipIter((args.c##OP())...);}, zip);}
    HELPER(begin) HELPER(end)
    HELPER(rbegin) HELPER(rend)
#undef HELPER
```

but it fails because `ZipIter::reference` is based on `IT::value_type`, which doesn't carry the constness with it.  I think I'd need to define a parallel `const_ZipIter` to support that.

---

From C++20 onwards, we can implement `operator <=>` instead of all the relational operators in `ZipIter`.

---

`std::size_t` is misspelt (and is missing its header), where it's used as a non-type template argument.

We're also missing an include of `<utility>`, for `std::swap` used in `ZipRef`.

---

I think we should be allowing argument-dependent lookup of `swap` here:

> ```
>   template <size_t I = 0>
>   void swap(const ZipRef& o) const {
>     std::swap(*(std::get<I>(ptr)), *(std::get<I>(o.ptr)));
>     if constexpr( I+1 < sizeof...(T) ) swap<I+1>(o);
>   }
> ```

I suggest:

```
    void swap(const ZipRef& o) const {
        swap_impl<0>(o);
    }

private:
    template <std::size_t I>
    void swap_impl(const ZipRef& o) const {
        using std::swap;
        swap(*std::get<I>(ptr), *std::get<I>(o.ptr));
        if constexpr(I+1 < sizeof...(T)) swap_impl<I+1>(o);
    }
```

I guess that reversing the order might make for simpler code, but could fail the strong exception guarantee if an element's `swap()` might throw.

Also with `swap()`, I think that this being `const` is sufficiently weird to justify a decent explanatory comment in the code.  It might save you trying to "fix" this "bug" later!

---

Just before our non-member swap, we have a `using` declaration:

```
using std::swap;
```

Not only do we not need this, it's also poor practice to inflict this on users of the header.

---

Misuse can give hard-to-detect problems.  For example, the program crashed when I tried passing inputs of different length.  We could add some error checking to the `Zip` constructor:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
```

```
    Zip(Container&... z)
        : zip{z...}
    {
        auto const len = {(zip.size())...,};
        if (std::adjacent_find(len.begin(), len.end(), std::not_equal_to()) != len.end())
            throw std::invalid_argument("array lengths differ");
    }
```

A little further work should be able to add the actual lengths to the exception message to improve its value to the programmer.

---

## Modified code

This is with my changes; I'm sure there's more improvements that could be made.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

template <typename ...T>
class ZipRef {
    std::tuple<T*...> ptr;
public:
    ZipRef() = delete;
    ZipRef(const ZipRef& z) = default;
    ZipRef(ZipRef&& z) = default;
    ZipRef(T* const... p): ptr(p...) {}

    ZipRef& operator=(const ZipRef& z)             { return copy_assign(z); }
    ZipRef& operator=(const std::tuple<T...>& val) { return val_assign(val); }

    template <std::size_t I = 0>
    ZipRef& copy_assign(const ZipRef& z) {
        *(std::get<I>(ptr)) = *(std::get<I>(z.ptr));
        if constexpr(I+1 < sizeof...(T)) return copy_assign<I+1>(z);
        return *this;
    }
    template <std::size_t I = 0>
    ZipRef& val_assign(const std::tuple<T...>& t) {
        *(std::get<I>(ptr)) = std::get<I>(t);
        if constexpr(I+1 < sizeof...(T)) return val_assign<I+1>(t);
        return *this;
    }

    std::tuple<T...> val() const {return std::apply([](auto&&...args) { return std::tuple((*args)...); }, ptr);}
    operator std::tuple<T...>() const { return val(); }

    void swap(const ZipRef& o) const {
        swap_impl<sizeof...(T)-1>(o);
    }

private:
    template <std::size_t I>
    void swap_impl(const ZipRef& o) const {
        using std::swap;
        swap(*std::get<I>(ptr), *std::get<I>(o.ptr));
        if constexpr(I) swap_impl<I-1>(o);
    }

public:
#define OPERATOR(OP)                                                    \
    bool operator OP(const ZipRef & o) const { return val() OP o.val(); } \
    inline friend bool operator OP(const ZipRef& r, const std::tuple<T...>& t) { return r.val() OP t; } \
    inline friend bool operator OP(const std::tuple<T...>& t, const ZipRef& r) { return t OP r.val(); }

    OPERATOR(==) OPERATOR(<=) OPERATOR(>=)
    OPERATOR(!=) OPERATOR(<)  OPERATOR(>)
#undef OPERATOR

};

template<typename ...IT>
class ZipIter {
    std::tuple<IT...> it;

    template<int N, typename... T> using NthTypeOf =
        typename std::tuple_element<N, std::tuple<T...>>::type;
    template<typename... T> using FirstTypeOf = NthTypeOf<0, T...>;

public:
    using iterator_category = typename std::iterator_traits<FirstTypeOf<IT...>>::iterator_category;
    using difference_type   = typename std::iterator_traits<FirstTypeOf<IT...>>::difference_type;
    using value_type        = std::tuple<typename std::iterator_traits<IT>::value_type ...>;
    using pointer           = std::tuple<typename std::iterator_traits<IT>::pointer ...>;
    using reference         = ZipRef<typename std::iterator_traits<IT>::value_type ...>;

    ZipIter() = default;
    ZipIter(const ZipIter &rhs) = default;
    ZipIter(ZipIter&& rhs) = default;
    ZipIter(IT... rhs): it(std::move(rhs)...) {}

    ZipIter& operator=(const ZipIter& rhs) = default;
    ZipIter& operator=(ZipIter&& rhs) = default;

    ZipIter& operator+=(const difference_type d) {
        std::apply([&d](auto&&...args) {((std::advance(args,d)),...);}, it); return *this;
    }
    ZipIter& operator-=(const difference_type d) { return operator+=(-d); }

    reference operator* () const {return std::apply([](auto&&...args) {return reference(&(*(args))...);}, it);}
    pointer   operator->() const {return std::apply([](auto&&...args) {return pointer(&(*(args))...);}, it);}
    reference operator[](difference_type rhs) const {return *(operator+(rhs));}

    ZipIter& operator++() { return operator+=(1); }
    ZipIter& operator--() { return operator+=(-1); }
    ZipIter operator++(int) {ZipIter tmp(*this); operator++(); return tmp;}
    ZipIter operator--(int) {ZipIter tmp(*this); operator--(); return tmp;}

    difference_type operator-(const ZipIter& rhs) const {return std::get<0>(it)-std::get<0>(rhs.it);}
    ZipIter operator+(const difference_type d) const {ZipIter tmp(*this); tmp += d; return tmp;}
    ZipIter operator-(const difference_type d) const {ZipIter tmp(*this); tmp -= d; return tmp;}
    inline friend ZipIter operator+(const difference_type d, const ZipIter& z) {return z+d;}
    inline friend ZipIter operator-(const difference_type d, const ZipIter& z) {return z-d;}

#define OPERATOR(OP)                                                    \
    bool operator OP(const ZipIter& rhs) const {return it OP rhs.it;}
    OPERATOR(==) OPERATOR(<=) OPERATOR(>=)
    OPERATOR(!=) OPERATOR(<)  OPERATOR(>)
#undef OPERATOR
};

template<typename ...Container>
class Zip {
    std::tuple<Container&...> zip;

public:
    Zip() = delete;
    Zip(const Zip& z) = default;
    Zip(Zip&& z) = default;
    Zip(Container&... z)
        : zip {z...}
    {
        auto const len = {(z.size())...,};
        if (std::adjacent_find(len.begin(), len.end(), std::not_equal_to()) != len.end())
            throw std::invalid_argument("array lengths differ");
    }

#define HELPER(OP)                                                      \
    auto OP() {return std::apply([](auto&&... args) { return ZipIter((args.OP())...);}, zip);}
    HELPER(begin) HELPER(end)
    HELPER(rbegin) HELPER(rend)
#undef HELPER

#define HELPER(OP)                                                      \
    auto OP() const {return std::apply([](auto&&... args) { return ZipIter((args.OP())...);}, zip);}
    HELPER(begin) HELPER(end)
    HELPER(rbegin) HELPER(rend)
    HELPER(cbegin) HELPER(cend)
    HELPER(crbegin) HELPER(crend)
#undef HELPER
};

#include <utility>
using std::swap;
template<typename ...T> void swap(const ZipRef<T...>& a, const ZipRef<T...>& b) { a.swap(b); }

#include <sstream>
template< class Ch, class Tr, class...IT, typename std::enable_if<(sizeof...(IT)>0), int>::type = 0>
auto& operator<<(std::basic_ostream<Ch, Tr>& os, const ZipRef<IT...>& t) {
    std::basic_stringstream<Ch, Tr> ss;
    ss << "[ ";
    std::apply([&ss](auto&&... args) {((ss << args << ", "), ...);}, t.val());
    ss.seekp(-2, ss.cur);
    ss << " ]";
    return os << ss.str();
}


#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> a {3,1,4,2};
    std::vector<std::string> b {"Alice","Bob","Charles","David"};

    auto const zip = Zip(a,b);

    for (const auto & z: zip) std::cout << z << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::sort(zip.begin(), zip.end());
    for (const auto & z: zip) std::cout << z << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Your solution to the problem with different length ranges won't work for input iterators (no way to measure length without consuming the range -> later iteration will fail) or infinite ranges (size measurement will never finish). A more general approach would be to use a sentinel returned by `Zip::end` that compares `true` to any `ZipIter` where any contained iterator is equal to its respective end iterator.

Comment: Yes, good point - I was seduced by the word `Container` into assuming we could use `size()` safely.  Can I claim in defence that it was only meant as an illustration that we could at least *try* validating input?

Comment: I attempted to modify the ADL of swap (which I also don't like in its current state) as you suggested, but I did not manage to satisfy the compiler. It's probably my fault, but it would be great if you could expand a bit on that.